# XAML timer-triggered binding update

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, timer, declarative

Suppose you have textbox whose value is time-dependent, like say, the the time passed since the application was started. Is it possible to express a solution in pure XAML which automagically re-evaluates the binding expression for the databound property, say every second?

So far I'm using a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: data-bound properties should update any time the source updates.  are you binding to either 1) a dependency property or 2) a property in a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (and for which you fire the PropertyChanged even any time the property changes)?

Comment: #2 - the scenario is a menu item expressing how long time has passed since a file was last opened (recently opened files); the text changes while the menu is shown and the time passes using a textual description (e.g. "a few seconds ago", "just over a minute ago", etc.)

Comment: then you should be set.  of course, the bit about keeping up with how much time has passed since a file has been opened is done in code (and, imo, properly so).  can you post an example of how you are currently doing it, or maybe how you don't want to do it?